# Why this case class can hold more parameters than it declares?

Tags: scala

See the code,

```
 case class Wrapped[A](elem: A)(implicit ordering: Ordering[A])
    extends Ordered[Wrapped[A]] {
    def compare(that: Wrapped[A]): Int = ordering.compare(this.elem, that.elem)
  }
```

I define a `case class` here.

and then call

`Wrapped(1,2,2,4)`.

To my surprise, even `Wrapped(1,2,3,4,5)` (any num of parameters) can work fine without compiling error.

Comment: Your wrapped instance only has a single argument - a `Tuple4[Int, Int, Int, Int]`.

Answer (score 15):

It's called auto-tupling.

The compiler will try to make up for the extra arguments by wrapping all of them in a tuple.

```
Wrapped(1,2,3,4)
```

gets automatically turned into

```
Wrapped((1,2,3,4))
```

By the way, this is an annoying and surprising feature and I really hope it will be eventually deprecated. In the meanwhile you have two compiler options available:

- `-Ywarn-adapted-args`, that warns in case of autotupling
- `-Yno-adapted-args`, that gives an error under the same circumstances

Example with warning:

```
scala -Ywarn-adapted-args

scala> case class Foo[A](a: A)

scala> Foo(1, 2)
<console>:10: warning: Adapting argument list by creating a 2-tuple: this may not be what you want.
        signature: Foo.apply[A](a: A): Foo[A]
  given arguments: 1, 2
 after adaptation: Foo((1, 2): (Int, Int))
              Foo(1, 2)
                 ^
res1: Foo[(Int, Int)] = Foo((1,2))
```

Example with error:

```
scala -Yno-adapted-args

scala> case class Foo[A](a: A)
defined class Foo

scala> Foo(1, 2)
<console>:10: warning: No automatic adaptation here: use explicit parentheses.
        signature: Foo.apply[A](a: A): Foo[A]
  given arguments: 1, 2
 after adaptation: Foo((1, 2): (Int, Int))
              Foo(1, 2)
                 ^
<console>:10: error: too many arguments for method apply: (a: (Int, Int))Foo[(Int, Int)] in object Foo
              Foo(1, 2)
                 ^
```

Comment: That's indeed a wierd "feature" I wasn't aware of.

Comment: Is "adapted args" synonymous with "autotupling"?

Comment: It's that plus automatic Unit insertion, which already deprecated now

Comment: Since `ordering ` is implicit, and I did't pass any to it.  How does the tuple be compared and ordered ?

Comment: There are implicit orderings available for tuples provided there are orderings for the individual elements; the ordering is by first element, then by second element and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Look closer to your code:

```
Wrapped(1,2,3,4,5)
res0: Wrapped[(Int, Int, Int, Int, Int)] = Wrapped((1,2,3,4,5))
```

Parameters are compacted into `Tuple` object. So you have `Wrapped[(Int, Int, Int, Int, Int)]` instead of desired `Wrapped[Int]`.